# Can't install any package with node npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, npm

I'm trying to install some node packages through npm, but it won't go.
I've already tried to install/unistall/update node, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 - Here is how i'm trying to install packages:

```
npm install underscore

npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR!   <head>
npm ERR!     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
npm ERR!     <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://img.sedoparking.com/registrar/dopark.js"></script>
npm ERR!   </head>
npm ERR!   <body style="display: none;">
npm ERR!     <script type="text/javascript">
npm ERR! var reg = 'sedonewreg';
npm ERR! document.write( '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"' + 'src="http://sedoparking.com/' + window.location.host + '/' + reg + '/park.js">' + '<\/scr' + 'ipt>' );
npm ERR!     </script>
npm ERR!  </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:235:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/home/smanastirliu/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:142:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:856:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:808:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:895:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/smanastirliu/local/bin/node" "/home/smanastirliu/local/bin/npm" "install" "underscore"
npm ERR! cwd /home/smanastirliu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/smanastirliu/local/bin/node" "/home/smanastirliu/local/bin/npm" "install" "underscore"
npm ERR! cwd /home/smanastirliu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/smanastirliu/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
smanastirliu@sviluppo69:~$ sudo npm install underscore
[sudo] password for smanastirliu: 
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR!   <head>
npm ERR!     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
npm ERR!     <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://img.sedoparking.com/registrar/dopark.js"></script>
npm ERR!   </head>
npm ERR!   <body style="display: none;">
npm ERR!     <script type="text/javascript">
npm ERR! var reg = 'sedonewreg';
npm ERR! document.write( '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"' + 'src="http://sedoparking.com/' + window.location.host + '/' + reg + '/park.js">' + '<\/scr' + 'ipt>' );
npm ERR!     </script>
npm ERR!  </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:235:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:142:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:856:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:808:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:895:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "underscore"
npm ERR! cwd /home/smanastirliu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/smanastirliu/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

and here is the debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'underscore' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.18
3 info using node@v0.10.5
4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
5 verbose read json /home/smanastirliu/package.json
6 verbose read json /home/smanastirliu/package.json
7 verbose cache add [ 'underscore', null ]
8 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="underscore" args=["underscore",null]
9 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
9 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
9 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
9 verbose parsed url   host: null,
9 verbose parsed url   port: null,
9 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
9 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
9 verbose parsed url   search: null,
9 verbose parsed url   query: null,
9 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'underscore',
9 verbose parsed url   path: 'underscore',
9 verbose parsed url   href: 'underscore' }
10 silly lockFile 64bc6893-underscore underscore
11 verbose lock underscore /home/smanastirliu/.npm/64bc6893-underscore.lock
12 silly lockFile 64bc6893-underscore underscore
13 silly lockFile 64bc6893-underscore underscore
14 verbose addNamed [ 'underscore', '' ]
15 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
16 silly lockFile 7629b758-underscore underscore@
17 verbose lock underscore@ /home/smanastirliu/.npm/7629b758-underscore.lock
18 silly addNameRange { name: 'underscore', range: '', hasData: false }
19 verbose url raw underscore
20 verbose url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './underscore' ]
21 verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
22 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 16:38:48
23 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
24 http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
25 verbose bad json <html>
25 verbose bad json   <head>
25 verbose bad json     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
25 verbose bad json     <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://img.sedoparking.com/registrar/dopark.js"></script>
25 verbose bad json   </head>
25 verbose bad json   <body style="display: none;">
25 verbose bad json     <script type="text/javascript">
25 verbose bad json var reg = 'sedonewreg';
25 verbose bad json document.write( '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"' + 'src="http://sedoparking.com/' + window.location.host + '/' + reg + '/park.js">' + '<\/scr' + 'ipt>' );
25 verbose bad json     </script>
25 verbose bad json  </body>
25 verbose bad json </html>
26 error registry error parsing json
27 silly registry.get cb [ 404,
27 silly registry.get   { date: 'Mon, 29 Apr 2013 14:39:02 GMT',
27 silly registry.get     server: 'Apache',
27 silly registry.get     'content-length': '521',
27 silly registry.get     connection: 'close',
27 silly registry.get     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' } ]
28 silly lockFile 7629b758-underscore underscore@
29 silly lockFile 7629b758-underscore underscore@
30 error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
30 error <html>
30 error   <head>
30 error     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
30 error     <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://img.sedoparking.com/registrar/dopark.js"></script>
30 error   </head>
30 error   <body style="display: none;">
30 error     <script type="text/javascript">
30 error var reg = 'sedonewreg';
30 error document.write( '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"' + 'src="http://sedoparking.com/' + window.location.host + '/' + reg + '/park.js">' + '<\/scr' + 'ipt>' );
30 error     </script>
30 error  </body>
30 error </html>
30 error
30 error     at Object.parse (native)
30 error     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:235:23)
30 error     at Request.self.callback (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:142:22)
30 error     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
30 error     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:856:14)
30 error     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
30 error     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:808:12)
30 error     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
30 error     at _stream_readable.js:895:16
30 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
31 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
31 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
31 error or email it to:
31 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
32 error System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
33 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "underscore"
34 error cwd /home/smanastirliu
35 error node -v v0.10.5
36 error npm -v 1.2.18
37 error type unexpected_token
38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Another example with Karma:

```
sudo npm install karma
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder/0.4.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/LiveScript/1.0.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul/0.1.22
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/growly
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder/0.4.2
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/LiveScript/1.0.1
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/growly
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul/0.1.22
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-0.10.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-0.10.2.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/-/dequeue-1.0.3.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.15.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.11.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls/-/prelude-ls-0.6.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-1.1.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-0.9.9.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars/-/handlebars-1.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fileset/-/fileset-0.1.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-1.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-0.0.22.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/utile/-/utile-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.15.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.11.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/-/dequeue-1.0.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls/-/prelude-ls-0.6.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-1.1.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-0.9.9.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars/-/handlebars-1.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fileset/-/fileset-0.1.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-1.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-0.0.22.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/utile/-/utile-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal/-/deep-equal-0.0.0.tgz
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-1.0.9.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/i/-/i-0.3.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal/-/deep-equal-0.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-1.0.9.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ncp/-/ncp-0.2.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/i/-/i-0.3.1.tgz
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/ncp/-/ncp-0.2.7.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/ncp/-/ncp-0.2.7.tgz
npm ERR! Error: 404 Not Found
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/smanastirliu/Scaricati/node-v0.10.5-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/fetch.js:57:12)
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:1596:14
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma"
npm ERR! cwd /home/smanastirliu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing source-map@>= 0.1.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/smanastirliu/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Calling the packages url from browser I get a strange response (same response for any url):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://img.sedoparking.com/registrar/dopark.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="display: none;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
var reg = 'sedonewreg';
document.write( '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"' + 'src="http://sedoparking.com/' + window.location.host + '/' + reg + '/park.js">' + '<\/scr' + 'ipt>' );
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

It seems to be a proxy error: I'm investigating

Comment: I am guessing you are facing connection problems or some . Try to open links giving 404 error like `http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore` in your browser. Are you using proxy ?

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I get always a same and strange response calling http://registry.npmjs.org/* in the browser. I'm now investigating why is this happening. Question updated with the http response

Comment: I found this on net: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mu-subdirectory-redirects-to-domains. Also check with your ISP if it is blocking/redirecting npm registry links.

Comment: Thanks! It was a DNS problem of our provider.

Answer (score 80):

```
npm install <packagename> --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Try specifying the registry with the install command.
Solved my problem.

Comment: I confirm that this solved my issue when installing Cloud9 hosted IDE (https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9)

Comment: I suspect this works because npm uses `https` by default, and by specifying this flag you're forcing `http` instead. See answer from Brendon Muir below.

Answer (score 60):

I had this issue, and doing `npm cache clean` solved it.

Comment: I wanted to chime in, i had this issue and `npm cache clean` didn't fix my issue (it normally does). I had to delete my `.npm` cache folder which in my case is located in `~/.npm`. You can use `npm cache ls` to find out where the cache is located. Just delete the folder, and it will reload cache the next time you run `npm`

Comment: Cache on Windows might be at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

Answer (score 31):

For future reference, this can also happen if [npm is down](https://twitter.com/npmjs/status/423185634581176320). That's how I found this question. Wish the first npm task was a server status check so there was a clearer error message.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check if http://registry.npmjs.org/ was actually up - sometimes you overlook the obvious.  Guess I'll wait 'til later.

Comment: I can tell when the registry goes down because that's when I get upvotes on this answer :)

Comment: @SimplGy when I check [status.npmjs.org](http://status.npmjs.org/) it says everything is up and running. But when I ping the registry it times out. Am I doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 20):

This is to do with SSL for some reason. If you set the registry to be plain http then it should work. You can set it to always be this via:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or as jairaj said, you can supply it in the command line.

Comment: This was correct for me. By default npm uses `https` and chokes on it even though the URL is fine and retrievable. Override it with `--registry` or this permanent fix and you're done. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

1.>Go to your this location

```
C:\Users\{your user name or ID}
```

2.> open .npmrc & Remove all content from .npmrc file.

3.>reopen your new command prompt

4.>again run the code , will work.

Answer (score 8):

Translated:

It happened the same to me and in my case in particular was because the **package.json was wrong**.
example:

```
{
   "name": "app",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "description": "any description",
   "main": "index.js",
   "author": "me", ->wrong
}
```

The **last comma** was left over and it gave me error any instalacción with npm in this proyect

then:

```
{
   "name": "app",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "description": "any description",
   "main": "index.js",
   "author": "me"
}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with ssl

you should use sudo. Follow below method to resolve the issue.

if you are getting this issue enter sudo npm config set strict-ssl false 
password: Enter current username password

then now run all ur command wit sudo sudo npm npm install -g underscore
password: Enter current username password

Even after if your getting error. 
Your proxy will be problem. few corporate proxy will be blocked, so you should use wifi or open network to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
npm install underscore
```

:)

There is no unserscore package in npm registry.

Comment: lol! Sorry for the typo, but this is not the problem: I updated the log, and as you can see it continue to happens, and of course it happens with any npm package

Comment: Problem is with proxy. Check you ur internet connection use open internet connection.

Comment: Problem is with proxy. Check you ur internet connection use open internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (not using proxy):

1. set registry mirror for npm..

   npm config set registry http://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry

found mirror from docs:https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry

2. after this try npm install if it works then try to install whatever you want otherwise follow below steps as well

3.npm install -g handlebar //i did because it was showing error in npm log but you can skip

4.after that try to set again official registry

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

5.now try to install whatever package you want :-)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is specifically getting `Unexpected token <`, and your package.json is fine, check your **npm-shrinkwrap.json** file! I had unresolved merge issues in mine, and fixing that resolved everything.

Comment: Same idea as this, check `package-lock.json` if you're having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from LAXIT KUMAR's recommendation, we've found that at times the registry URL can get corrupted, not sure how this is happening, however to cure, just reset it:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

The 404 disappeared as it was going to the correct location again.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a -g to the end of my install fixed this for me. ex:
    npm install uglify-js -g

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem in Ubuntu 15.10 while installing gulp-preetify.

The problem was:

1. `Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-preetify`
2. I tried by using `npm install gulp-preetify` but it didn't worked.
3. Again i tried using: `npm i gulp-preetify`
   and it just got installed.

I cannot guarantee that it will solve your problem but it won't harm with a single try.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unlucky enough to be switching back and forth from a network behind a proxy and a network NOT behind a proxy, you may have forgotten that your NPM config is set to expect a proxy.

For me, I had to open up ~/.npmrc and comment out my proxy settings (while at home) and vice versa while at work (behind the proxy).

Answer (score 1):

This means the npm command is getting an HTML document instead of whatever format it is looking for. In my case, I was using [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia). When I no longer wanted to use it, I accidentally used this command to reset the registry:

```
npm config set registry https://www.npmjs.com/
```

which was wrong, and it should have been the command already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966697/5800527).
Read [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) if none of the answers solve this problem, and you can probably figure out where the incorrect URL is present and clear it off, and set the registry to the correct URL:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

try `npm update` and then try installing it with `sudo npm i <package__name>`

Answer (score -3):

There is a possibility that your `package.json` is causing this.

Parse your `package.json` to find the unexpected token

or

Delete your `package.json` file and create one through

```
npm install
```