# Bower Command Not Found

Tags: bower

I am trying to get Bower up and going, but stuck with the Command Not Found error. 
I have run

`npm install -g bower`

And there are some ERR! showing though not enough info to help me understand if it is relevant. I pasted the output into a gist so not to take up a ton of space here,

https://gist.github.com/27c49b8a1a5eb552cb8a

I also read about the PATH issue, but I believe I already have that set up,

`echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/bin:/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/ryan/repos/git-friendly`

Not sure what to Google next so I came here, thank you for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080468/error-installing-bower-err-tar-unpack-untar-error

Comment: possible duplicate of ["command not found" after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation)

Comment: So npm cache clean did nothing. I had already seen the other question that this may be a duplicate of and I checked my PATH and /usr/local/share/npm/bin: is already there. That is what led to my confusion and posting here.

Answer (score 25):

Try to remove your bower like

```
npm remove bower
```

Then reinstall it using admin account

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 8):

If you have already installed bower and you are getting command not found error, try this.(else run **npm install -g bower**)

1.) Goto command prompt.

2.) And run this cmd: **set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\ "Your username" \AppData\Roaming\npm** (Please do not forget to replace your username in the command).

3.) Now the system will be able to find bower and you can install anything you want! :-)

Comment: you sir... you saved my mental health

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

This will solve your issue.