# Why am I getting Unexpected token '\u0000' when using npm install -g package

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

This is probably a Windows specific issue but I haven't found any information when googling this issue.  I had been using ionic framework which relies on Cordova (or Phonegap).  However, the problem is not specific to any of these packages.  I see this error quite often.  So, the error is when I run a command such as the following:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

However, I could substitute various other packages and get the same error.  I'll paste the snippet (very brief) below of the error message.  What is strange is that I had an ionic project working in that directory earlier.  Then today it told me that ionic could not be found.  My hunch is that this is a different issue than the main issue I am describing here.

I installed git bash so I do have a linux-like environment that I could try.  I would just select Git Bash for a bash window with various bash commands.  If there is an easier way to fix this for Windows users, please let me know.  I have seen courses on Pluralsight where the instructors seem to be happily using npm with no problems.  Also, when I use yeoman, I also at some point, in many cases, get the same error.
The error is

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: c:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\amdefine\1.0.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse.
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice,
Bruce

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Via [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280382/cant-install-any-package-with-node-npm) it could be that you just have to do:

`npm cache clean`.

But, also try the other methods suggested there like adding the registry option:

`npm install <packagename> --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Or, if you've been mingling with the `package.json` file by yourself, check if it's valid.

Comment: I apologize for not commenting sooner.  I had been in chat and got the same answer you suggested first, of cleaning the cache.  I'll have to check the other related question and the --registry flag, as I don't know that off the top of my head.  But, no, I haven't mingled with the package.json files, these were fresh installs of packages available on npmjs.org...  though, I did try to update them, using the install command instead of update.

Comment: No problem, so basically the cache cleaning helped in the end, or the reinstall?

Comment: FWIW, the cache cleaning was all I needed.