# I have executed command-npm cache clean but there is a error pm ERR! Failed to parse json npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1

Tags: npm, installation, atom-editor

I try to install atom plugin-**atom-vim-mode-plus**
but there is an error below.I have executed the command **npm cache clean** but it does not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp8Es.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got a blue screen in the middle of an npm install and after restart kept getting this (failed to parse json Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1 error. npm uninstall didn't help either.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547789/why-am-i-getting-unexpected-token-u0000-when-using-npm-install-g-package) was the best solution, but I followed the error message to check the package.json files in the AppData folder and found the package.json files to be empty. So I deleted the folder (e.g. chartjs-color-string as per the error message (in the attached image).

[image: Failed to parse JSON Unexpected token at 'u0000' at 1:1]