# meteor command throwing errors

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I get following error when i run command: meteor

```
[[[[[ C:\projects\employees ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.    
Unable to resolve some modules:


 "loadash" in /C/projects/employees/server/main.js (os.windows.x86_32)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save loadash

W20160625-21:00:28.388(1)? (STDERR)
W20160625-21:00:28.628(1)? (STDERR) C:\Users\XPS\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
W20160625-21:00:28.637(1)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20160625-21:00:28.643(1)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20160625-21:00:28.650(1)? (STDERR) Error: Can't find npm module 'loadash'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
W20160625-21:00:28.661(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (C:\projects\employees\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:203:17)
W20160625-21:00:28.670(1)? (STDERR)     at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:21:1)
W20160625-21:00:28.680(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:88:1)
W20160625-21:00:28.686(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.import (C:\Users\XPS\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\modules\0.6.4\npm\node_modules\reify\lib\runtime.js:70:16)
W20160625-21:00:28.698(1)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.main.js (C:\projects\employees\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\app.js:22:20)
W20160625-21:00:28.723(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160625-21:00:28.731(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160625-21:00:28.736(1)? (STDERR)     at C:\projects\employees\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\app.js:57:1
W20160625-21:00:28.747(1)? (STDERR)     at C:\projects\employees\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:297:10
W20160625-21:00:28.756(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

---

i get following error if i try to install lodash using this command: meteor npm install --save loadash

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\XPS\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\XPS\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "loadash"
npm ERR! node v0.10.45
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/loadash
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'loadash' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\employees\npm-debug.log
```

---

I tried everything on this link: [Can't install any package with node npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280382/cant-install-any-package-with-node-npm)

Problem is still there. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a typo. You want to install `lodash`, not `loadash`. Look in your `main.js` file for the typo and fix it.

Comment: yeah realised that just after posting the question. Thanks