# NPM install error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm using npm install and validate the package JSON content is valid and I'm getting the following error:

After reading on the web, I did `"rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"` (even if I didn’t see any package lock there) and did also `npm cache clean -f` which doesn’t help, also configured registry.

See *[Can't install any package with node npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280382/cant-install-any-package-with-node-npm)*

I'm using the latest npm, 6.2.0.

The error in the logs is:

```
159 silly saveTree ├── express@4.16.3
159 silly saveTree ├── passport-http@0.3.0
159 silly saveTree └── passport@0.3.2
160 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<html>
160 verbose stack <head><title>...'
160 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
160 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
160 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
160 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
160 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Is there is something else I can do?

Comment: if using Visual Studio Community edition 2017 check that you are in the project folder in the Package Manager Console and not in the solution folder, this caught me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package.json, or maybe other JSON file is incorrect. You must first fix JSON errors.

Comment: Please try remove your node_modules and reinstall

Answer (score 12):

Do the following:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
3. Run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache verify
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Node Modules and package-lock JSON file, solves this issue in many cases.

These are the steps to be followed:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
3. Verify the cache
4. Run `npm install` again.

Let's use **rimraf**

1. Install rimraf globally

   npm install rimraf -g
2. Remove node modules

   rm -rf node_modules
3. Remove `package-lock.json`

   rimraf package-lock.json
4. Verify cache

   npm cache verify
5. Install the modules again

   npm install

Answer (score 0):

For people who have removed `node_modules` and facing error after `npm install`.
This can also be a problem if you have a preinstall script under `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
....
```

Since `npm-force-resolutions` looks for node_modules to resolve. To fix it, just comment the preinstall script, run `npm install` and then revert the comment and run `npm install` again just to keep things verified.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in NestJS and I found out that the error was in nest-cli.json and not in any other file.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue, as well.

This solution in [Can't install any package with node npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280382/cant-install-any-package-with-node-npm) helps me.

The command is below:

```bash
npm install <packagename> --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But, this is painful. After a while, I found that I set the wrong registry mirror.

- Firstly, I use the command below to find out my registry

  ```bash
  npm config ls -l
  ```

  Then I found the value is `http://www.npmjs.org/`
- Secondly, I use the command below to fix it

  ```bash
  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
  ```

After that, I solved it!