# npm can't install packages in a windows terminal

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

I try to work with node js ,when i run the command >npm install 
express ,i'm logging in the terminal as an administrator in windows, it 
cannot install packages.

I have this error on terminal after running the previous command:

```
[..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
I need some help please,i have no experience in node js developping.
```

ps:I have a connection wifi behind a proxy

```
informations proxy:
hostname:23.11.201.32
user:ensias-tp
password:xxxxxxxx
port number:2342
```

What commands that i use to configure the proxy?

Comment: Try out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install any package with node npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280382/cant-install-any-package-with-node-npm)

Comment: i try the solution but it doesn't work ,i try the command npm config set proxy ''http://ensias-tp:wpass1234@23.11.201.32:2342/" but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Open the .npmrc file

`npm config edit`

Check the following values:

```
proxy=http://user:passsword@host.domain.com:port/
https-proxy=http://user:passsword@host.domain.com:port/
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```